# i am getting this error when i try to preview query in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I create a new query and when i try to preview it i get the following error.

i followed this link and created a content type Book and add content part product to it.

http://skywalkersoftwaredevelopment.net/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-5

could not execute query

[ select distinct TOP (@p0)  contentite0_.Id as col_0_0_ from Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord contentite0_ inner join Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord contentite1_ on contentite0_.ContentItemRecord_id=contentite1_.Id inner join Customer_ProductPartRecord productpar2_ on contentite1_.Id=productpar2_.Id where contentite0_.Published=1 order by contentite0_.Id ]

[SQL: select distinct TOP (@p0)  contentite0_.Id as col_0_0_ from Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord contentite0_ inner join Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord contentite1_ on contentite0_.ContentItemRecord_id=contentite1_.Id inner join Customer_ProductPartRecord productpar2_ on contentite1_.Id=productpar2_.Id where contentite0_.Published=1 order by contentite0_.Id]

```
**ProductPartFilter.cs**

using Orchard.Localization;
using Orchard.Projections;
using Orchard.Projections.Descriptors.Filter;
using Skywalker.Webshop.Models;
using IFilterProvider = Orchard.Projections.Services.IFilterProvider;

namespace Skywalker.Webshop.Filters
{
public class ProductPartFilter : IFilterProvider
{
    public Localizer T { get; set; }

    public ProductPartFilter()
    {
        T = NullLocalizer.Instance;
    }

    public void Describe(DescribeFilterContext describe)
    {
        describe.For(
            "Content",          // The category of this filter
            T("Content"),       // The name of the filter (not used in 1.4)
            T("Content"))       // The description of the filter (not used in 1.4)

            // Defines the actual filter (we could define multiple filters using the  fluent syntax)
            .Element(
                "ProductParts",     // Type of the element
                T("Product Parts"), // Name of the element
                T("Product parts"), // Description of the element
                ApplyFilter,        // Delegate to a method that performs the actual  filtering for this element
                DisplayFilter       // Delegate to a method that returns a descriptive  string for this element
            );
    }

    private void ApplyFilter(FilterContext context)
    {

        // Set the Query property of the context parameter to any IHqlQuery. In our    case, we use a default query
        // and narrow it down by joining with the ProductPartRecord.
        context.Query = context.Query.Join(x =>     x.ContentPartRecord(typeof(ProductPartRecord)));
    }

    private LocalizedString DisplayFilter(FilterContext context)
    {
        return T("Content with ProductPart");
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Why do you need to create a filter for that? There already is a content type filter for projections. Also, can you please provide the entire error message?

Comment: i have noticed that if i create content part and content type using Orchard Admin option everything including query works fine. but if i create content part and content type using module (code) it never works . So if i create a query of content created by module it only shows datetime against record but if i create a query for content type created by admin option it works fine and shows all properties of record.

Comment: That doesn't mean that you should create an unnecessary filter, it means that there probably is something wrong in your migrations. Please show your migration.

Comment: there was a problem in driver and placement.info file, its resolved . thank you so much for helping